# How to use static const struct from a class as a real const - i.e. an array size

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, constants, member

I was asked to provide solution for the following problems:

There is a structure defining some int parameters:

```
struct B {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

One wanted to define this structure as const static members in other classes **(not only for this `class A` - there are other classes expected to have the same set of constants)** .

And one wanted to use them as real integral constants:

```
// .h file
class A {
public:
  static const B c; // cannot initialize here - this is not integral constant
};
// .cpp file
const B A::c = {1,2};
```

But cannot use this constant to make for example an array:

```
float a[A::c.a];
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make `A::c` `constexpr` you can initialise it inline and use its members as a constant:

```
struct A {
    static constexpr B c = {1, 2};
};

float a[A::c.a];
```

Comment: I cannot use it - "the support for constexpr was first added to GCC in 4.6" - we have earlier versions. But your solutions is better than mine (+1) for more  recent compilers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I find, is to change the `struct` to `template` `struct` with const members.

```
template <int AV, int BV>
struct B {
  static const int a = AV;
  static const int b = BV;
};
template <int AV, int BV>
const int B<AV,BV>::a;
template <int AV, int BV>
const int B<AV,BV>::b;
```

And usage:

```
// .h file
class A {
public:
  typedef B<1,2> c; 
};
```

And an array:

```
float a[A::c::a]; 
//          ^^ - previously was . (dot)
```

Comment: Why you didnt post it in your answer?

Comment: @DenisErmolin where should he post the solution?

Comment: use `enum {a = AV, b = BV}`, the common IntToType idiom can simplify it a little bit

Comment: @YanZhou yes, but the real problem is to have exactly the same set of constants in different classes - not only `class A`...